# Working with a csv file and outputting json in python

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I'm using pandas in python to take a csv file, do some minor transformations on it and then outputting the two columns as a json file. I want two values `timestamp` and `value`. I only want the two new columns and to drop the rest of the file so that it looks like:

`{"timestamp[0]":value[0],"timestamp[1]":value[1],"timestamp[2]":value[2],..}`

But right now with my code I'm still getting all the old csv data and the part I want is appended (and in the format) :
`{stuff I don't want, "timestamp":"timestamp[0]", "value":value[0]},{...}{...}`

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import delorean as dl

def doThings(infile, outfile):
    f = pd.read_csv(infile)
    hmCols = {"timestamp": [], "value": []}

    for i, row in f.iterrows():
        total = row["Playspace_1"] + row["Playspace_2"] + row["Playspace_3"] + row["Playspace_4"]
        hmCols["timestamp"].append(row["Timestamp"])
        hmCols["value"].append(total)

    f["timestamp"] = hmCols["timestamp"] #old code
    f["value"] = hmCols["value"] #old code
    f.to_json(outfile, orient="records") #old code

    pd.DataFrame(hmCols).to_json(outfile, orient="records") #From user Turn

doThings("test.csv", "heatmapData.json")
```

Any help would be appreciated

So based on Turn's help I changed the code per his suggestion. Now I get the output:

`[{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808753,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982811944,"value":1} ...`

Now I need to transform that to:

`[{"1417982808063":1},{"1417982808063":1},{"1417982808753":1},{"1417982811944":1}...]`

Answer (score 1):

What if you change this:

```
        f["timestamp"] = hmCols["timestamp"]
        f["value"] = hmCols["value"]
        f.to_json(outfile, orient="records")
```

to:

```
        pd.DataFrame(hmCols).to_json(outfile, orient="records")
```

**Edit to add:**

I misunderstood the output you were looking for. What if you changed the whole loop to this (with an `import json` added at the top):

```
    def doThings(infile, outfile):
        f = pd.read_csv(infile)
        result = []
        for i, row in f.iterrows():
            total = row["Playspace_1"] + row["Playspace_2"] + row["Playspace_3"] + row["Playspace_4"]
            result.append({row["Timestamp"]: total})

        with open(outfile, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(result, fp)
```

Comment: So that gets me very close! I now have `[{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808753,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982811944,"value":1}`

Comment: I misunderstood the output format you were looking for. Answer updated.